# How to loop a form with multiple choices, to produce multiple forms?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have the user input in all the subjects they take from a drop down list, while also inputting their grade, chosen from a dropdown list. I'm using a form for each of the inputs, but I realised it's bad code if I am copy-pasting all the forms. And if I make any changes to the dropdown list, I have to amend it 6 times. I wanted to do a For loop but it's HTML. Any way to fix this issue?

Wanted to do a For loop but its HTML so I dont know what's the syntax or is there any way to loop in HTML. Or am I supposed to move this code over to Javascript?

`

```
<form class="form">
     <select name="Subjects">
         <option disabled selected value>Subject</option>
         <option value="English">English</option>
         <option value="Maths/Science">Elementary Maths</option>
         <option value="Maths/Science">Additional Maths</option>
         <option value="Maths/Science">Physics</option>
         <option value="Maths/Science">Chemistry</option>
         <option value="Humans">Literature</option>
         <option value="Humans">Combined Humans (SS+History)</option>
         <option value="Humans">Mother Tongue</option>
     </select>
     <select name="Grade" id="Grades">
          <option disabled selected value>Grade</option>
          <option value="1">A1</option>
          <option value="2">A2</option>
          <option value="3">B3</option>
          <option value="4">B4</option>
          <option value="5">C5</option>
          <option value="6">C6</option>
          <option value="7">C7</option>
          <option value="8">E8</option>
          <option value="9">F9</option>
     </select>
     <br>
```

`

It will show one form. I need to have 6 forms of the exact same layout. I don't want to copy paste it. I rather use a loop of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way using `cloneNode()`:

1. Give ids to your inputs
2. In JavaScript clone both inputs
3. Before appending them to your form, change their id by
4. create a line break element
5. Append the line break and the cloned inputs

**N.B:** If you want to duplicate the whole form instead of the inputs, use the same method by cloning the form element and append it to the boday or to the container div.

```js
  for(i=1; i<6; i++) {
        var subject=document.getElementById("subject");
        var newSubject = subject.cloneNode(true);
        newSubject.id='subject'+i;

        var grade=document.getElementById("grade");
        var newGrade = grade.cloneNode(true);
        newGrade.id='garde'+i;

        var linebreak = document.createElement("br");

        document.getElementById("myform").appendChild(linebreak);        
        document.getElementById("myform").appendChild(newSubject);        
        document.getElementById("myform").appendChild(newGrade);        
    }
```

```html
<form class="form" id="myform">
     <select id="subject" name="Subjects">
         <option disabled selected value>Subject</option>
         <option value="English">English</option>
         <option value="Maths/Science">Elementary Maths</option>
         <option value="Maths/Science">Additional Maths</option>
         <option value="Maths/Science">Physics</option>
         <option value="Maths/Science">Chemistry</option>
         <option value="Humans">Literature</option>
         <option value="Humans">Combined Humans (SS+History)</option>
         <option value="Humans">Mother Tongue</option>
     </select>
     <select  name="Grade" id="grade">
          <option disabled selected value>Grade</option>
          <option value="1">A1</option>
          <option value="2">A2</option>
          <option value="3">B3</option>
          <option value="4">B4</option>
          <option value="5">C5</option>
          <option value="6">C6</option>
          <option value="7">C7</option>
          <option value="8">E8</option>
          <option value="9">F9</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I understand why you need to change the id?

Comment: Because the attribute ID must be unique, it's value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree.

Answer (score 0):

We can create two arrays for subjects and grades and iterate over them and add each subject/grade to corresponding select tag.

```
const subjects = [
  { name: "English", value: "English" },
  { name: "Elementary Maths", value: "Maths/Science" },
  { name: "Additional Maths", value: "Maths/Science" },
  { name: "Physics", value: "Maths/Science" },
  { name: "Chemistry", value: "Maths/Science" },
  { name: "Literature", value: "Humans" },
  { name: "Combined Humans (SS+History)", value: "Humans" },
  { name: "Mother Tongue", value: "Humans" }
];

const grades = [
  { name: "A1", value: "1" }, { name: "A2", value: "2" },
  { name: "B3", value: "3" }, { name: "B4", value: "4" },
  { name: "C5", value: "5" }, { name: "C6", value: "6" },
  { name: "C7", value: "7" }, { name: "E8", value: "8" },
  { name: "F9", value: "9" }
];

const createOption = option => {
    let optionEl = document.createElement('option');
    optionEl.value = option.value;
    optionEl.innerText = option.name;
    return optionEl;
}

function addOptions(subjectTagId, options) {
    const select = document.getElementById(subjectTagId);
    options.forEach(option => select.appendChild(createOption(option)));
}

addOptions('subjects', subjects);
addOptions('grades', grades)
```

Note: Add an id `'subjects'` to the select tag for subjects just like you have for the select tag for grade. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The anwer to your question is **No**. You can't loop in HTML. HTML is a descriptive language, it describes the elements of your page.

To enable itself with programming capabilities, HTML defines the `<script>` tag. Browsers support it and are able to interpret and execute the code it contains. For historic reasons, the code is written in **javascript** language.

In your case, you need to change the contents of the page programmatically. To do so, you don't change the HTML, but manipulate the **DOM**, the internal representation of the page in the browser, once the page has finished loading. The javascript support in browsers has standardized some methods to access the DOM and manipulate (insert, delete, change) the DOM contents.

You first must create a `<script defer>` tag inside your page `<head>`. The `defer` attribute specifies that you want your code to run after the complete page has been loaded and the DOM has been constructed.

```
<script defer>
</script>
```

Then you need to (1) find your `<form>` in the page (2) copy it five times (3) giving all of them (including the original) unique IDs and (4) inserting the copies into the DOM after the original form, before the next element that follows the original form.

```
let originalForm=document.querySelector("form");   //(1)
let insertionPoint=form.nextSibling;  //(4)
originalForm.id="form-1";  //(3)
for (let i=2;i<=6;i++) {  //(2)
  let copied = originalForm.cloneNode(true); //(2)
  copied.id='form-'+i; //(3)
  originalForm.parentNode.insertBefore(copied, insertionPoint); //(4)
}
```